# Int overflow coerced to 0?

Tags: haskell

If I write a recursive factorial like this :

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * (fact (n-1))
```

ghci tells me it has the type `(Eq p, Num p) => p -> p`.

I expect Haskell to be smart and enable this factorial implementation to be fast. So if I write : `fact (10 :: Int)` all of it is going to be fast math with `Int`s, if I write `fact (1000 :: Integer)`, all or some of the computation is going to be slow math with `Integer`s.

ghci is helpful here :

```
λ: :t fact (2 :: Int)
fact (2 :: Int) :: Int
λ: :t fact (2 :: Integer)
fact (2 :: Integer) :: Integer
```

I have two questions that come out of this :

Q1 : What happens when I run

```
λ: fact (10 :: Int)
>3628800
λ: fact (40 :: Int)
>-7060926325325235253252...
λ: fact (66 :: Int)
>0
```

Obviously Haskell cannot compute the correct result for larger arguments as it will overflow. So I'm not surprised at the result for `fact 40`, I get similar results up to `fact 65`. But starting at `fact 66` the function always returns 0. How come?

Q2 : Given a call to `fact`, is it correct that all recursive calls to fact will use the same type, even when Int could've been substituted for Integer in some of the calls (i.e. the whole computation is slower than it could be if the compiler was able to decide at runtime between Int and Integer on a per-call basis).

Comment: Because `0` * any other number is `0`.

Comment: I guess that's a good point that if ``fact 66`` is 0 then everything upwards will be 0 as well. But is there a non-trivial reason why ``fact 66`` is zero? If I compute ``toInteger((fact 65 :: Int)) * 66`` I get a value that I don't understand why it would be 0 as an Int.

Comment: wel this is due to the fact that `Int` has a fixed number of bits, and each time, the higher bits are ommited. At some point the value will be zero. Especially since frequently we multiply with a power of two, hence we "shift" the bits out of the lowest bits.

Comment: Yep, there's a reason: the last 64 bits of `Numeric.showHex (product [1..66 :: Integer]) ""
"10b395943e6086f3f811b267cc58286d7c1eb06b9a4de25bacad2cd8d5dc2b0000000000000000"`

Comment: @ARRG It might be enlightening to compare `toInteger (fact 65 :: Int) * 66` and `(2^64) * 33 :: Integer`.

Comment: While it is true that fact (10 :: Int) will use 64 bit arithmetic, and this is faster than arbitrary precision Integer arithmetic, the difference is likely swamped by the overhead of making indirect calls to a multiply function. If you were doing this in a real program and this mattered then you would want to use the SPECIALIZE pragma to tell GHC to generate a version of fact hard-coded for Int. https://www.stackbuilders.com/tutorials/haskell/ghc-optimization-and-fusion/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Int` is a 64 bit integer (on your platform at least), so the results you're seeing are modulo 2^64 (and then interpreted as signed). `fact 66` is the first factorial that happens to be a multiple of `2^64`, therefore `` fact 66 `mod` 2^64 `` is 0. Since every factorial is a multiple of the previous factorials, all larger factorials are also multiples of `2^64`.

> Given a call to fact, is it correct that all recursive calls to fact will use the same type

Yes, the type of `*` is `Num a => a -> a -> a`, so both operands of `*` must have the same type, which is also the type of its result. Therefore, in `n * fact (n-1)`, `fact (n-1)` must have the same type as `n` (and `n-1` which also has the same type as `n` because `-` has the same type as `*`).

Comment: Also expressible as: `sum [Data.Bits.countTrailingZeros n | n <- [1 .. 66 :: Int]]`, which counts the powers of 2, at that point reaching 64.

Answer (score 6):

> I get similar results up to `fact 65`. But starting at `fact 66` the function always returns `0`. How come?

Well if `fact` for a given number produces `0`, then for every other `fact` with a larger index, the result will be `0` as well, since `n * 0` is still `0`. A type like `Int` has a fixed number of bits (for example 16 bits for `Int16`). In case we multiply two larger numbers, that produce a number with more than 16 bits, the higher bits are ignored. So For example:

```
  fact 7 |    5040 |   0001 0011 1011 0000
x      8 |  x    8 | x                1000
------------------------------------------
  40 320 |  40 320 |   1001 1101 1000 0000
------------------------------------------
 -25 216 | -25 216 |   1001 1101 1000 0000
```

here no values are shifted out of the `Int16`, but because of the signed interpretation, we get negative values. Later we multiply with `9`, and then get:

```
  fact 8 |  -25 216 |   1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1101 1000 0000
x      9 | x      9 | x                                    1001
---------------------------------------------------------------
  40 320 | -226 944 |   1111 1111 1111 1100 1000 1001 1000 0000
---------------------------------------------------------------
 -30 336 |  -30 336 |                       1000 1001 1000 0000
```

So the CPU will perform the calculations in a larger register (for example 32 bits), and the take the lowest 16 bits of that result. Since every multiplication with an even number, will shift the values at least one position to the left, the set bits will eventually get shifted out of the integer representation with a fixed number of bits (although if we have more bits, this process will of course take longer).

For a number with *n* bits, we reach zero in less than *2×n* steps (since each time the index is even, we shift it *at least* one position to the right).

> **Q2:** Given a call to fact, is it correct that all recursive calls to fact will use the same type, even when Int could've been substituted for Integer in some of the calls

Types are *not* decided at run time (so "*per call*"), but at compile time. Haskell analyzes the function by first assuming it has a type `a -> b` where `a` and `b` can be anything.

Next it makes some analysis:

```
fact 0 = 1
```

means that the input type `a` and the output type `b` have to be of the `Num` typeclass. Furthermore we perform an *implicit* equality check (well Haskell will perform `(0 ==)` behind the curtains). So now we know that the type is:

```
fact :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => a -> b
```

Now we can analyze the recursive call:

```
fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

this is equivalent to:

```
-- equivalent to
fact n = (*) n (fact (n-1))
```

Haskell does *not* assume that this recursive `fact` call has the same type. The recursive call thus has type `(Num c, Num d, Eq c) => c -> d` so to speak.

We however can analyze the function [**`(*) Num e => e -> e -> e`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-). Note that in Haskell when we perform multiplication, the two operands and the result all have the same type. Since the first operand is `n`, we know that `e ~ a` and `e ~ d` (the result type of the recursive call), and `e ~ b` (the result of our outer `fact`). So we know that `e ~ a ~ b ~ d`. So that means that `a` and `b` are the same type, hence `fact` has type:

```
fact :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a
```

and therefore we know that for the recursive call, `c ~ d ~ a`. Hence the recursive call also has type `fact :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a` (recursive function call). So indeed, here the recursive call uses the same types.

Answer (score 2):

Answering question 2, there is only one way this type checks:

```
fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

Specializing `fact` at `Int`, the recursive call must also be specialized at `Int`.

```
(fact :: Int -> Int) n = n * (fact :: Int -> Int) (n-1)
```

In other situations it may happen that a recursive call gets defaulted to `Integer`, but if you always compile with (at least) `-Wall`, defaulting triggers a warning.